Text rendering scrolling performance using gtk + cairo
// gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` main.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 cairo`

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <cairo.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024
#define LINE_SPACING 5
#define FONT_SIZE 20

typedef struct {
    char **lines;
    int line_count;
    int max_line_length;
} AppData;

static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, AppData *data) {
    cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Monospace", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
    cairo_set_font_size(cr, FONT_SIZE);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < data->line_count; i++) {
        cairo_move_to(cr, 0, FONT_SIZE + i * (FONT_SIZE + LINE_SPACING));
        cairo_show_text(cr, data->lines[i]);
    }

    return FALSE;
}

static void on_destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        g_printerr("Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file) {
        g_printerr("Could not open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    AppData data;
    data.lines = NULL;
    data.line_count = 0;
    data.max_line_length = 0;

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        data.lines = realloc(data.lines, sizeof(char *) * (data.line_count + 1));
        if (data.lines == NULL) {
            g_printerr("Memory allocation error.\n");
            fclose(file);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        data.lines[data.line_count] = strdup(line);
        if (strlen(line) > data.max_line_length) {
            data.max_line_length = strlen(line);
        }
        data.line_count++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Text Renderer");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300);
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(on_destroy), NULL);

    GtkWidget *scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    GtkWidget *drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new();

    int height = data.line_count * (FONT_SIZE + LINE_SPACING);
    int width = data.max_line_length * (FONT_SIZE / 2);

    gtk_widget_set_size_request(drawing_area, width, height);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top(drawing_area, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom(drawing_area, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start(drawing_area, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end(drawing_area, 0);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window), drawing_area);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), scrolled_window);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(drawing_area), "draw", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), &data);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

This performs terribly under measly 2M text file when scrolling
Yes, i know Gtk.TextView exists. Gtk text widgets are limited for what i'm trying to do (projects like text editor with fancy features like multiple cursors, terminal emulator (i also know that vte exists)), plus i just want to do this for educational reasons.
I want to focus on improving rendering performance, not file reading from disk performance (cause, my assumption - rendering is the main problem).
First idea is to render text in chunks nearest to viewed area, which i don't know if its even possible.
Another idea is to use opengl instead of cairo to render it, i don't think it would help much.
Here is command i used to generate random text file to test scrolling performance:
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=2M | tr -dc '[:print:]\n' > random_text.txt

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)


Yes, i know Gtk.TextView exists.

Did you look at its implementation for ideas?
I found gtk_widget_set_overflow(widget, GTK_OVERFLOW_HIDDEN);. I have no clear clue what it does, but it sounds like it could help.
Besides that.... this seemed like a bad idea. I could not even figure out how it draws anything.
Another thing I did was to look at Gtk.ScrolledWindow. Its documentation says that it has special support for scrollable widgets:

Widgets with native scrolling support, i.e. those whose classes implement the GtkScrollable interface, are added directly. For other types of widget, the class GtkViewport acts as an adaptor, giving scrollability to other widgets.

Gtk.TextView implements GtkScrollable, so... perhaps this is used to not draw offscreen parts?

First idea is to render text in chunks nearest to viewed area, which i don't know if its even possible.

That sounds like a good idea. :-)
On https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.DrawingArea.html, I found:

and that drawing is implicitly clipped to the exposed area.

So, you might be able to use cairo_clip_extents() to get the bounding box of the clip area and then "do something" to only draw there. Your drawing code seems to have an idea of where each line is and how large it is (FONT_SIZE, LINE_SPACING).

Another idea is to use opengl instead of cairo to render it, i don't think it would help much.

Yeah... gut feeling, but I also do not think so.
Disclaimer: I do not really have much clue what I am talking about. I am mostly guessing.
